# Iterating rasters from two different folders using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, con

I have created a simple script like that, which is working fine

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:/2017/wgs84/project'
direction = arcpy.ListRasters("*WIND*","TIF")
print direction
speed = arcpy.ListRasters("*SPEED*","TIF")
print speed
for k in range(len(direction)):
  outCon = Con(Raster(direction[k]) == 1, Raster(speed[k]), 0)
  outCon.save('speed0' + str(k) + '.TIF')
  print ('done')
print ('done final')
```

I have different wind direction files(rasters) in different folders and speed files in another one. This code works for what I need, only if I have pasted the speed files and the wind files in the same folder.
What if I wanted to create a list from one folder and a list from another so as not having to copy paste every time?

I tried to define also a different workspace for direction and different for speed but apparently its not working(maybe the last env.workspace is "hold" in the memory?)

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:/speed'
speed = arcpy.ListRasters("*SPEED*","TIF")
print speed
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:/2017/wgs84/project'
direction = arcpy.ListRasters("*WIND*","TIF")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list the raster names without full path/workspace:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:/speed'
speed = arcpy.ListRasters("*SPEED*","TIF")
```

So when you change workspace afterwards, arcpy will not know where to find them.

Try adding full path to the raster lists using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:/speed'
speed = arcpy.ListRasters("*SPEED*","TIF")
speed = [os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,r) for r in speed]
```

And then do the same for the wind rasters in the other folder.